# Permissions error for homebrew 'brew update' on linux

Tags: activerecord, homebrew, freetds, tiny-tds

I've got a permission error with Homebrew ported to linux via this handy how-to:
http://blog.frameos.org/2010/11/10/mac-homebrew-ported-to-linux/comment-page-1/#comment-2208

I’ve got the same problem:

```
>  $ brew update –verbose
> 
>  git checkout -q master  fatal: Unable to create
> ‘/opt/homebrew/.git/index.lock’: Permission denied  Error: Failure
> while executing: git checkout -q master
```

Tried changing the file permission on the ‘index’ file, no luck. My final goal is to be able to install freetds and tinytds on my Ubuntu server (brew install freetds) so if there's another way to do so please lemme know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, the small tutorial was horribly broken...

In a nutshell:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo mkdir /opt/homebrew
sudo chown `whoami` -R /opt/homebrew
git clone git://github.com/rubiojr/homebrew.git /opt/homebrew
```

Looks like you need to fix permissions when running with an unprivileged user?

```
chown -R `whoami` /opt/homebrew
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I still can't do 'brew install freetds' though, it doesn't seem to be syncing the recipes for me, I had to vim a copy of the freetds.rb as it's not in the recipes folder, just an FYI!